# UITableView grouped remove top margin in Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I've created a ListView in Xamarin, I have a custom renderer that renders it as a grouped UITableView. The problem is that the Top Header is taking up space. How do I remove this empty space(margin) in Xamarin C#? 
I saw a solution in swift and objective-c, but I don't know how to translate it.

This is a solution for Swift:

```
var frame = CGRect.zero
frame.size.height = 1
tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: frame)
```

How can this be done in C#?

Comment: Do you mind putting your custom renderer code for the grouped tableview here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47851691/xamarin-forms-how-to-make-ios-listview-native-grouped-style-with-headers I have a bounty on it as I can't get it to work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var frame = CGRect.Empty;
frame.Height = 1;
MyStuffTableView.TableHeaderView = new UIView(frame);
```